# Anti Sway Bar Opengl

Tags: c++, glm-math

I am implementing an anti sway bar to prevent my car from overturning at low speeds, according to the example of the ode wiki. This is my code.

```
GLfloat amt = 0.0f,displacament = 0.0f;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  dVector3 anchor2,anchor1,axis;
  dJointGetHinge2Anchor2(hinge[i],anchor2);
  dJointGetHinge2Anchor(hinge[i],anchor1);
  dJointGetHinge2Axis1(hinge[i],axis);

  displacament = glm::dot((glm::vec3(anchor1[0],anchor1[1],anchor1[2]) - glm::vec3(anchor2[0],anchor2[1],anchor2[2])),glm::vec3(axis[0],axis[1],axis[2]));

  if(displacament > 0){
    amt = displacament * 80.0f; //80.0f
    if(amt > 15.0f)amt = 15.0f; //15.0f;
    dBodyAddForce(bodyR[i],-axis[0]*amt,-axis[1]*amt,-axis[2]*amt);
    dBodyAddForce(bodyR[i^1],axis[0]*amt,axis[1]*amt,axis[2]*amt);

    dReal const *wp = dBodyGetPosition(bodyR[i]);
    dBodyAddForceAtPos(body_chasis,-axis[0]*amt,-axis[1]*amt,-axis[2]*amt,wp[0],wp[1],wp[2]);
  }
}
```

[image]

To turn use this code.

```
dJointSetHinge2Param(hinge[2],dParamLoStop,ang);
dJointSetHinge2Param(hinge[2],dParamHiStop,ang);

dJointSetHinge2Param(hinge[3],dParamLoStop,ang);
dJointSetHinge2Param(hinge[3],dParamHiStop,ang);
```

[image]

[image]

At low speed it seems to work well. The problem is that at high speed it seems that the force applied to the wheels (This part of the code above) forces the steering wheels to return almost to their initial position.

[image]

```
dBodyAddForce(bodyR[i],-axis[0]*amt,-axis[1]*amt,-axis[2]*amt);
dBodyAddForce(bodyR[i^1],axis[0]*amt,axis[1]*amt,axis[2]*amt);
```

[image]

In this way, the car makes turns too wide. Does anyone know what happens?